# Fail when linking a C++ project

Tags: c++

I am getting the following linking error:

```
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable environment
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Cluster::euclideanCluster(std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > > > const&, KdTree*, float)", referenced from:
      ProcessPointClouds<pcl::PointXYZ>::Clustering(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> >, float, int, int) in environment.cpp.o
      ProcessPointClouds<pcl::PointXYZI>::Clustering(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >, float, int, int) in environment.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

In `processPointClouds.cpp` I am calling `Cluster::euclideanCluster` as:

```
#include "quiz/cluster/cluster.hpp"
...
template<typename PointT>
std::vector<typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr> ProcessPointClouds<PointT>::Clustering(typename pcl::PointCloud<PointT>::Ptr cloud, float clusterTolerance, int minSize, int maxSize)
{
...
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> cluster_vec = Cluster::euclideanCluster(...);
...
}
```

My `cluster.hpp`:

```
    #ifndef CLUSTER_H_
    #define CLUSTER_H_

    #include "kdtree.h"

    struct Cluster
    {

        static std::vector<std::vector<int>> euclideanCluster(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& points, KdTree* tree, float distanceTol);
    };


    #endif /* CLUSTER_H_ */
```

And my `cluster.cpp`:

```
#include "cluster.hpp"
std::vector<std::vector<int>> Cluster::euclideanCluster(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& points, KdTree* tree, float distanceTol)
{
...
}
```

Why am I getting this linking error? I am totally lost.

---

### EDIT

My CMakeLists.txt now looks like:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

add_definitions(-std=c++11)

```
set(CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "${CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT, "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk")

project(playback)

find_package(PCL 1.2 REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(src/quiz/ransac)
add_subdirectory(src/quiz/cluster)


add_executable (environment src/environment.cpp src/render/render.cpp src/processPointClouds.cpp src/quiz/cluster/cluster.cpp)
```

And now after including cluster.cpp in `add_executable` I get:

```
[ 54%] Linking CXX executable quizCluster
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/quiz/cluster/quizCluster] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/quiz/cluster/CMakeFiles/quizCluster.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have removed the main from cluster.cpp because the only main that I want to have in the executable comes from `src/environment.cpp`

```
#include "sensors/lidar.h"
#include "render/render.h"
#include "processPointClouds.h"
// using templates for processPointClouds so also include .cpp to help linker

#include "processPointClouds.cpp"

// Some methods

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << "starting enviroment" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Most likely, `cluster.cpp` is not actually part of your project's build configuration, and is not being compiled and/or linked with.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you are right but now if I add it in the executable I get another link error, I have updated the question

Comment: Well, is there a function named `main` in any of the source files that are part of your project?

Comment: Yes, in environment.cpp

Comment: Show it. Perhaps it has a wrong signature. It's not a method of some class, is it?

Comment: I have edited to show environment.cpp

Comment: Looks like there is a mismatch between 32bit dependencies and a 64bit executable.